# Rotating ImageView with RotateAnimation flickers between degree positions (Android)

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I have a problem with rotating an ImageView and getting it to stay pointing in the correct direction. Essentially the ImageView is an arrow that is supposed to always be pointing to the edge or corner of the screen that it's along (determined by the degree of the device from the gyroscope), but it just flickers between incorrect positions. For example, if the pointer starts in the top right corner of the screen and is pointing to that corner, then is supposed to move and point to the top of the screen, the x-y position will move correctly, but the pointer bounces between pointing to the top left corner and the top right corner.

To set the position of the pointer I have this:

```
public int pointerDegree = 0;
public void rotatePointerTo(int degree)
{
    if(degree==pointerDegree) //if it's already set to the degree it needs to be moved to
        return;
    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(pointerDegree, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setDuration(1);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    pointer.startAnimation(rotate);
    pointerDegree = degree;
}
```

Which is called in the OnSensorChanged function like this:

```
 int baseDegree = (int)degree%360;
    if(baseDegree > -5 && baseDegree < 5)
        rotatePointerTo(-90);
    else if(baseDegree >= 5 && baseDegree <= 85)
        rotatePointerTo(0);
    else if(baseDegree > 85 && baseDegree < 95)
        rotatePointerTo(45);
    else if(baseDegree >= 95 && baseDegree <= 175)
        rotatePointerTo(90);
    else if(baseDegree > 175 && baseDegree < 185)
        rotatePointerTo(135);
    else if(baseDegree >= 185 && baseDegree <= 265)
        rotatePointerTo(180);
```

I know when I call rotatePointerTo() the degree I'm using as the parameter may not be correct - I just filled it in with random values while I try to figure out the flickering issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger to identify the values that are being passed to OnSensorChanged ?

Comment: @OYRM yeah, that was the first thing I did. It was hard to tell where the issue is, since OnSensorChanged is being called a ton, and whenever it was hitting the breakpoints it was being set correctly - it was just basically impossible to catch it when it was acting incorrectly because it was going so quickly.

Comment: There is a practice known  as debouncing.  Set up logic which keeps a record and averages input so that highs and lows are lost on average. You can couple that with debugging to find outliers if you like.  Raw sensor data can show a lot of variation,  data processing may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering issue might be at this line :

```
rotate.setDuration(1);
```

That means you are animating the View for only 1 millisecond, which is really, really short.

You probably meant :

```
rotate.setRepeatCount(1);
```

which means you are playing the animation once.

I recommend you look into this class : [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) its really easy and straight forward and can save you a lot of your RotateAnimation code by rotating your view like this f.e. :

```
pointer.animate()
    .rotationBy(pointerDegree)
    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator)
    .setDuration(100);
```

Theres more rotationX and rotationY methods in that class, be sure to check all available methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it all out and let you know how it goes. I knew there might be a better way of doing the entire rotation, so I'll definitely checkout the ViewPropertyAnimator class.